# VB6 code line endings are changed when added to Git?

Tags: git, azure-devops, vb6

It seems to be complicated to push Old projects (VB6 projects) and cloning them. I can push all my vb6 project onto the DevOps repository but when I clone it to make some test, I can remark the project doesn't work anymore. The end of line are not the same. I stay in the Windows configuration.

I executed normaly the different operation to push the code onto devOps with

- git init
- git remote add origin
- git config --global core.autocrlf true
- git add .
- git commit -m “New project added”
- git push -u origin master

so when I create another folder and clone the project here and open my VB6 project, I can observe the end of lines are different so It becomes impossible to run the code. Do you have any idea or experience with this problem ?

Comment: Ask on Git? - This has nothing to do with VB6 coding.

Comment: Clearly, from the descriptions, you need to retain the Windows line ending convention, CR-LF, instead of it being converted to (probably) just LF.  Some git option somewhere, I'd suppose? As @JohnEason states, this is not a vb6 issue.

Comment: It is possible to make Git preserve CRLF data exactly as is. In fact, that's the default on any sane system ... which means it's *not* the default on most Windows installations. :-) I recommend *turning off* `core.autocrlf`; *do* use `.gitattributes` if and as appropriate. There is a (small) minefield here so experiment before you commit to any particular method (if you'll pardon the overuse of the verb *commit* here).

Answer (score 5):

Consider adding a [.gitatttribute file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) to your project's folder with the following lines in it:

```
# Visual Basic 6 source files
*.frm eol=crlf
*.bas eol=crlf
*.cls eol=crlf
*.ctl eol=crlf
*.vbp eol=crlf
*.vbw eol=crlf
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it worked !!! I have had to create a folder copy paste my code into it. Insert in the .git folder the .gitattributes files and push everything. It worked perfectly. If someone encounters the same problems I could described the way I followed

Comment: If it worked (for you), you may want to consider to mark this anwser "as accepted" _(or something the like, not sure what the actual option is called)_.